# Git, working between local branch and remote

Tags: git

I cloned a repository and got a master branch. From the master I created a local branch "abc".
Now the remote may have progressed. The branches look like this:

```
>git branch -a
* abc
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

1. How do I see the diff between local branch abc and remote.
2. How do I get the remote changes merged to my local banch "abc".
3. Can I push my local changes from "abc" directly to remote, or will I have to go via my local master.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `git diff origin/master..abc` for a diff between origin’s master and your local abc. Note that this reflects the state of your local repository, so if you want to make sure that all new changes from the remote are there, `git fetch` first.
2. In general `git pull` or more explicit `git pull origin master`. If you want to pull to `abc` you can also `git fetch` first to get all remote changes into your local repository (as remote branches) and then manually merge using `git merge origin/master`.
3. `git push origin <targetbranch>`. So if you want to create a branch `abc` on the remote, use `git push origin abc`. If you want to push to origin’s master, use `git push origin master`. This will fail if the remote cannot fast forward though, in that case you need to push explicitely with `--force`.

Comment: thanks that helps alot, some followup queries on same: (2) git fetch is not specific to any branch, can I do that from any local branch?

Comment: Yeah `git fetch <remote>` will fetch all branches from that remote, so you can execute it from wherever you want.

Comment: (2) "git fetch" is not specific to any branch? can I do "git fetch" from "abc" branch? Will there be any difference if I do "git fetch" from "abc" branch or master

Comment: In the eg above, it should be: "git fetch remotes/origin/master" ?

Comment: No, specifying `remotes/origin/master` won’t work as that’s the full ref-path to the remote branch `master` of the remote `origin`. You only fetch from remote repositories, so you just specify `origin`: `git fetch origin`.